# Gitlab ci artifacts not found

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

. Hello, can someone tell me, why gitlab cannot find my artifacts?

Logfile:

```
$ ls -la /build/Project*.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1641 Nov 25 21:18 /build/Project-1.0.zip
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /build/Project*.zip: no matching files
```

CI File:

```
package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - ... ... ...
    - ls -la /build/Project*.zip
  only:
    - master
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "/build/$CI_PROJECT_NAME*.mkp"
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The path of artifacts has to be relative to and be a child of $CI_PROJECT_DIR.

Comment: Why would they not put that in the documentation?!

Answer (score 8):

Make it relative to $CI_PROJECT_DIR.

Put it like:

```
    - cp -r $(pwd)/target/*.html $CI_PROJECT_DIR/report
    - ls -la $CI_PROJECT_DIR/report
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - report/*.html
```

To know more go to: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/15530

Comment: That's not enough. Only being relative to $CI_PROJECT_DIR is not enough. It also has to be a child of it. E.g. this would also fail: `../../test`